# Employee count over time - LinkedIn API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

One of the Premium Insights on Company Pages on Linkedin is the [employee count history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKZ42.jpg) (it goes around two years back). Is it possible to access that through API?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself before asking?

Answer (score 1):

The `employee-count-range` is available from the Company Profile API, but it doesn't look like *historical* data is available.

Sample request to retrieve the current employee count range:
`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}:(id,name,ticker,description,employee-count-range)?format=json`

Reference: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_profile

Comment: In API v2 its present as `"staffCountRange": "SIZE_2_TO_10"` when you query this API endpoint (no projection needed)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the info which is available in the insights
`https://www.linkedin.com/sales-api/salesApiEmployeeInsights/" + str(id) + "?timeSpan=SIX_MONTHS` 
You have to use the id which you can find in the link of the sales navigator, and you can change the timeSpan, you should use inspect element on the insights page and find this request, in order to find the headers of the request in order to add them to your request.

Comment: this works, but you need a Premium Account, and it's not the historical data.